# Visual Studio Live Share: As a host how to give access/permission to my participant

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

I'm trying to do Quick Fixes (the lightbulb icon at the left margin of the editor) as a participant in live share, but I'm getting this error.

[image]

As a host how do I give access/permission to my participant?

Answer (score 5):

Enable this in your user settings:

> **Liveshare > Languages: Allow Guest Command Control**
>
> Allow guests to run commands via Code Actions ("Quick Fixes") and CodeLens